# SPOnline: Read attributes of users from Azure AD

Tags: office-365, active-directory, sharepoint-hosted-app, user-profile-property

I have a requirement to read AD attributes of users (not just logged in user) from my SP hosted app. This includes information like Department, Manager, location and some other custom attributes.

Is it possible to get this info from AD given that current logged in user has enough access to read the attributes? Please provide details of how this can be done in JavaScript code of the App. We can't read from user profile as it doesn't have everything mapped.

Answer (score 0):

If AD properties are already mapped with user profile properties, then you can get them using REST API.

```
http://siteurl/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetMyProperties
```

Just make GET request to the above end-point, it will return you current user's properties.

**Get all properties of Specific User SP Online**

```
http://siteurl/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetPropertiesFor(accountName=@v)?@v='i:0%23.f|membership|vardhaman@siteurl.onmicrosoft.com'
```

[SharePoint 2013: Get UserProfile Properties with REST API](http://www.vrdmn.com/2013/07/sharepoint-2013-get-userprofile.html)

**PS:** You can not get all users at once. You have to find them by their login name.

Comment: thanks for the info, however, we need to read from AD as customer has not mapped the attributes to user profile. I will update the question.

Comment: your customer will have to consider the mapping otherwise it is not possible using javascript